# pytest - Mark tests with certain parameter value as pytest.mark.skip

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

My goal is to mark as `@pytest.mark.skip` tests which are parametrized with given value.

Example test:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', [value_not_to_filter, value_to_filter])
def test_example(param):
    ...
```

I would like to filter tests in `pytest_collection_modifyitems` from `conftest.py`:

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        if value_to_filter in item.params: # this line is pseudocode, I'm looking for way to check if item was parametrized by some value
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.skip(reason='some reason'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use the hooks here, but the code won't be nice as you will have to dig through `pytest`'s internals and private accessors. An autouse fixture skipping the tests is IMO a much more clean solution:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_some_tests(request):
    if 'param' in request.fixturenames and request.getfixturevalue('param') == value_to_filter:
        pytest.skip(reason='param is value_to_filter')
```